# User populated list within a form

Tags: javascript, html

I am looking for an example of a user populated list within a form, I would like users to be able to write into a box and then add it into another box so they can have more that one "item"

The one I currently have when I press the add to list button it acts like the complete form button and just sends the email

I'm not looking for you to do it for me would just like an example or the correct name for what I want, thanks!

Comment: I'm still not sure what you exactly want, but to prevent "acts like the complete form button and just sends the email" try to add to the button in question a property "type="button"". This should prevent submitting.

Comment: Yeah that fixed that issue thanks! can I have a form within a form?

Comment: No, you can not have a form within a form (at least not when it comes to the DOM structure). If I understand you correctly, you want something that extends the functionality of a normal HTML `select` field so that the user can additionally add own “options” (?) – this is what is commonly referred to as a “Combo-Box”, and was not available in HTML 4; however, HTML5 has added the `datalist` element for that. http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-datalist-element | http://www.scriptol.com/html5/combobox.php